# pytest monkeypatch class method while calling super

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module `loaders` with class "Loader" with class method "load". During test, I want to append some additional steps to "Loader.load" to account for test specific data post-processing, so essentially overriding it. How do I properly do that?

I tried creating a mock class which inherits Loader and use monkeypatch.setattr("loaders.Loader", mock_loader), but this only works when I run one single test, but not when I run all tests.

loaders.py

```py
class Loader:
   def load():
      # do something
      return data
```

test.py

```py
from loaders import Loader
class MockLoader(Loader):
   def load():
      data = super().load()
      # do something to data
      return data

def test_loader_special1(monkeypatch):
   monkeypatch.setattr("loaders.Loader", MockLoader)
   #run test logic 1

def test_loader_special2(monkeypatch):
   monkeypatch.setattr("loaders.Loader", MockLoader)
   #run test logic 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying [Niels answer also posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675071/14536215) to use `monkeypatch`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_load(monkeypatch):
    real_func = Loader.load

    def mock_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Mock load() called")
        data = real_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        data += " and mock"
        return data
    monkeypatch.setattr(Loader, "load", mock_func)
```

You can then mark the fixture to be loaded for all tests in the testing module with:

`@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)`

or mark the tests to use specified fixtures with:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_load")
def test_loader_special1():
...
```

### Mocking the whole class

If you want to mock the whole class, you need to mock it before you import the class for it to take effect, or you could just import the module so you don't have the import statements sprinkled around:

```
import loaders

class MockLoader(loaders.Loader):
    def load(self):
        data = super().load()
        data += " and mock"
        return data

def test_loader_special1(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("loaders.Loader", MockLoader)
    data = loaders.Loader().load()
    print(f"{data=}")
    assert data == "real and mock"
```

Comment: this isn't any different from what I was trying right? only that I was creating a mock class and here it's a mock method. Why wouldn't mock class work in the way I did it?

Comment: @siminsimisim If you want to mock the whole class, you have to mock it before importing it. Check the edit

Answer (score -1):

Use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) or [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) either via the builtin library [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) or the external library [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) :

> patch() acts as a function decorator, class decorator or a context
> manager. Inside the body of the function or with statement, the target
> is patched with a new object.

Where it is explicitly documented that the patch is only applicable per test:

> When the function/with statement exits the patch is undone.

The patch will be used to wrap around your real implementation so that you can perform any necessary steps before and/or after calling it.

**loaders.py**

```
class Loader:
   def load(self):
      print("Real load() called")
      return "real"
```

**test_loaders.py**

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

from loaders import Loader


@pytest.fixture
def mock_load(mocker):
    real_func = Loader.load

    def mock_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Mock load() called")
        data = real_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        data += " and mock"
        return data

    # Option 1: Using pytest-mock + new
    mocker.patch.object(Loader, 'load', new=mock_func)

    """
    Alternative ways of doing Option 1. All would just work the same.

    # Option 2: Using pytest-mock + side_effect
    mocker.patch.object(Loader, 'load', side_effect=mock_func, autospec=True)

    # Option 3: Using unittest + new
    with patch.object(Loader, 'load', new=mock_func):
        yield

    # Option 4: Using unittest + new
    with patch.object(Loader, 'load', side_effect=mock_func, autospec=True):
        yield
    """

def test_loader_special1(mock_load):
    data = Loader().load()
    print(f"{data=}")
    assert data == "real and mock"


def test_loader_special2(mock_load):
    data = Loader().load()
    print(f"{data=}")
    assert data == "real and mock"


def test_loader_special3():
    data = Loader().load()
    print(f"{data=}")
    assert data == "real"


def test_loader_special4(mock_load):
    data = Loader().load()
    print(f"{data=}")
    assert data == "real and mock"
```

Output:

```
$ pytest test_loaders.py -q -rP
....                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ test_loader_special1 ___________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mock load() called
Real load() called
data='real and mock'
__________________________________________________________________________________________ test_loader_special2 ___________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mock load() called
Real load() called
data='real and mock'
__________________________________________________________________________________________ test_loader_special3 ___________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Real load() called
data='real'
__________________________________________________________________________________________ test_loader_special4 ___________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mock load() called
Real load() called
data='real and mock'
4 passed in 0.01s
```